# Classes of the previous model after transfer learning

Tags: python, tensorflow, transfer-learning

I have Resnet50 model, now in the model I wanted to add 4 more classes.

I used transfer learning to do so.
Now I am having 4 classes only in the model. I lost those previous classes.
I don't know where did I go wrong. can someone tell me what happened?

basically, when I update, I want all the class in the same model so that I don't need to use Two models.

here is a section of my code-:

```
model = ResNet50(input_tensor=image_input, 
include_top=True,weights='imagenet')

last_layer = model.get_layer('avg_pool').output
x= Flatten(name='flatten')(last_layer)
out = Dense(4, activation='softmax', name='output_layer')(x)
custom_resnet_model = Model(inputs=image_input,outputs= out)
custom_resnet_model.summary()

for layer in custom_resnet_model.layers[:-1]:
     layer.trainable = False

custom_resnet_model.layers[-1].trainable
```

`custom_resnet_model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])`

one suggested sol in a comment I tried. when I pass `output=[out, model.output]`, I got following error-: `ValueError: Shapes (None, 4) and (None, 1000)`.

when I applied suggested solution, this is the summary (last few layers)of the model-:

```
conv5_block3_out (Activation)   (None, 7, 7, 2048)   0           
conv5_block3_add[0][0]
```

---

```
avg_pool (GlobalAveragePooling2 (None, 2048)         0           
conv5_block3_out[0][0]
```

---

```
flatten (Flatten)               (None, 2048)         0           
avg_pool[0][0]
```

---

```
output_layer (Dense)            (None, 4)            8196        
flatten[0][0]
```

---

```
 predictions (Dense)             (None, 1000)         2049000     
 avg_pool[0][0]
```

Comment: You do realize you haven't given us any code to help you right?

Comment: From what you said, I can only say that it went wrong when you deleted 9 classes ;-) Do you have any code?

Comment: let me add code! @kyriakosSt @Andre!

Comment: @André added it, take a look

Comment: @kyriakosSt added it, take a look

Comment: you have set one output, and this is a dense layer with 4 neurons. What do you expect to get? If you also want the output of resnet, add output=[out, model.output].

Comment: and the what should i change in `custom_resnet_model.layers[-1].trainable`....... ??   my last two layers are this `output_layer (Dense)            (None, 4)            8196        flatten[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
predictions (Dense)             (None, 1000)         2049000     avg_pool[0][0]               `

Comment: @Kaveh `ValueError: Shapes (None, 4) and (None, 1000) are incompatible`  this error I am getting!

Comment: Please update your question with any new information. Additionally I think you should explain more about what do you mean by 13 class in your last model, while you have 4 class data. It is recommended to add a minimal code which is possible to reproduce your error.

Comment: Updated now, please take a look @Kaveh